# Как в Unity указать начальное число частиц?

Tags: unity3d

В Unity создаю ParticleSystem. По умолчанию у него сначала нет ни одной частицы. Подскажите, что  поменять в настройках, чтобы с самого начала эмуляции в системе уже было, например, 10 частиц.

Comment: Параметор `Prewarp ☑ ` начинает не с нуля а с постоянного цикла. Если нужен разовый выбрас, то в `Emision` есть `Bursts`.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за помощь